# cin.getline does not work with 2d arrays

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a sentence from a text file and store it in a 2D array. I am using the function cin.getline. I am trying to store each sentence of the text file to a row of the 2D array.read is my ifstream object.  Below is a sample of my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    int k=0;
    read.getline(people.wishlist[i][k], MAX); // store in row 0 when i is 0
}

// what my text file looks like: 

// Hey how is your day
// whats up
```

The error message I am getting:

> `error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::getline(_Elem *,std::streamsize)':`
>   `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char *'`

Can someone suggest a good method to solve this problem for me? Thanks

Comment: Try eliminating the second bracets [] `read.getline(people.wishlist[i], MAX);`

Comment: its only reads the first char of the sentence in the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on a 2D char array `people.wishlist[i][k]` stands for a single `char` (`i`th row and `k`th column), but `getline` expects a string of them `char*`.

You need a pointer to a 1D char array, which you can get indexing just one other dimension. (with `i`) You could try it this way:

```
read.getline(people.wishlist[i], MAX);
```

Comment: it only reads the first char of the sentence, not the entire sentence

Comment: What are `wishlist`'s dimensions? How do you know what it reads? debugger, printf?

Comment: i declared it as char wishlist[100][100]

Comment: If you print `people.wishlist[i]` it should print the whole sentence. If you print `people.wishlist[i][k]` it will print just the first character, because the second dimension is just the character.

Comment: @Nick why when indexing with one dimension, it becomes a pointer but two dimensions its no longer a pointer

Comment: @Lim Because when you index both dimensions, it is like if you were specifying row and column (like a coordinate), which gives you a single element on a 2D array. When you just index 1 dimension, it is like you are just specifying row, and that gives you the entire row with all its elements.

Comment: @Lim:  A so-called 2d array is actually an array of arrays.  When you index an array, you get one of its elements.  So if you index an array of arrays of chars, you get an array of chars.  An array is implicitly convertible to a pointer to its first element.  So, `wishlist[i]` gives you an array of chars, which is implicitly convertible to a pointer to `wishlist[i][0]`.  But `wishlist[i][0]` is not an array.  It is one element of the array `wishlist[i]`, and since `wishlist[i]` is an array of chars, `wishlist[i][0]` is a char.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you are passing a `char` where it expects a `char*`. Specifically you are passing the first element of the array, when you want to be passing the pointer to the start of the array.

As @Nick suggests, try this

```
read.getline(people.wishlist[i], MAX);
```

Comment: it only reads the first char of the sentence, not the entire sentence